# I am trying to insert loop data into database but it is giving an error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to insert loop data into database with laravel, but it returns the following error:

> ErrorException in Grammar.php line 118:
>   Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\App\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 678 and defined

**View:**

```
<input name="product_id[]" type="hidden" class="rid" value="13">
<input type="hidden" name="product_name[]" value="Popins"><input type="hidden" name="product_code[]" value="2323">
<input name="unit_price[]" type="hidden" value="170">
<input name="quantity[]" type="text" value="2" id="" >
```

**Controller**

```
for($i=0; $i<count($product_name);$i++){
    $newSafety = new saleItems;
    $newSafety->product_id = $request->unit_price;
    $newSafety->sale_id   = $request->unit_price;
    $newSafety->product_code   = $request->product_code;
    $newSafety->product_name   = $request->product_name;
    $newSafety->quantity   = $request->quantity;
    $newSafety->unit_price   = $request->unit_price;
    $newSafety->gross_total= $request->unit_price;
    $newSafety->save();
}
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? Please dont TAG SPAM

Comment: And which is **line 678** in the **12 lines** you have shown us

Comment: @RiggsFolly am using laravel 5.2 and Grammar.php that you are saying that has line 768 is a laravel file. i did not make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like each of input that you are passing through your request are arrays and you trying to assign them to non arrays attributes of the $newSafety object.

try this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($product_name);$i++){
    $newSafety = new saleItems;
    $newSafety->product_id = $request->unit_price[i];
    $newSafety->sale_id   = $request->unit_price[i];
    $newSafety->product_code   = $request->product_code[i];
    $newSafety->product_name   = $request->product_name[i];
    $newSafety->quantity   = $request->quantity[i];
    $newSafety->unit_price   = $request->unit_price[i];
    $newSafety->gross_total= $request->unit_price[i];
    $newSafety->save();
```

}